# <p:fileUpload> hide the following component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF2,primefaces2.1 (using netbeans 7.0.1 and glassfish3.1)
the problem that i am facing from a while is after using the  the button below it dont appear(if I add component below the fileupload it's ok but not after!)
after a lot of observing I have remarked that the problem is when I remove the table(which I have use it to organize my components) the button (adduser) appear !

this is the code page.xhtml

```
<table border="1" align="center" style='width:1004px;height:100px;' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
       <h:form>

       <tr><td>   
               <h:outputLabel value="Nom" /><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.nom}" />
               <br /></td></tr>
             <tr><td>    <h:outputLabel value="Prenom"/> <h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.prenom}" />
                     <br /></td></tr>
            <tr><td> <h:outputLabel value="Etat Civil"/>
                                 <h:selectOneMenu id="etatcivil" value="#{AddPerson.etatCivil}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Monsieur" itemLabel="M"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Madam" itemLabel="Mme"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Madmoiselle" itemLabel="Mlle"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>

                    <br /></td></tr>

            <tr><td>   <h:outputLabel value="Date de naissance "/> 


                                      <h:selectOneMenu id="jour" value="#{AddPerson.jour}">
                                      <f:selectItem itemValue="00" itemLabel=""/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="01" itemLabel="01"/> <f:selectItem itemValue="02" itemLabel="02"/><f:selectItem itemValue="03" itemLabel="03"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="04" itemLabel="04"/><f:selectItem itemValue="05" itemLabel="05"/><f:selectItem itemValue="06" itemLabel="06"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="07" itemLabel="07"/><f:selectItem itemValue="08" itemLabel="08"/><f:selectItem itemValue="09" itemLabel="09"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/><f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="11"/><f:selectItem itemValue="12" itemLabel="12"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="13" itemLabel="13"/><f:selectItem itemValue="14" itemLabel="14"/><f:selectItem itemValue="15" itemLabel="15"/>   
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="16" itemLabel="16"/><f:selectItem itemValue="17" itemLabel="17"/><f:selectItem itemValue="18" itemLabel="18"/>  
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="19" itemLabel="19"/><f:selectItem itemValue="20" itemLabel="20"/><f:selectItem itemValue="21" itemLabel="21"/>   
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="22" itemLabel="22"/><f:selectItem itemValue="23" itemLabel="23"/><f:selectItem itemValue="24" itemLabel="24"/>    
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="25" itemLabel="25"/><f:selectItem itemValue="26" itemLabel="26"/><f:selectItem itemValue="27" itemLabel="27"/>     
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="28" itemLabel="28"/><f:selectItem itemValue="29" itemLabel="29"/><f:selectItem itemValue="30" itemLabel="30"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="31" itemLabel="31"/>
                                         </h:selectOneMenu>


                                <h:selectOneMenu id="mois" value="#{AddPerson.mois}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="00" itemLabel=""/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="01" itemLabel="Janvier"/> <f:selectItem itemValue="02" itemLabel="Fevrier"/><f:selectItem itemValue="03" itemLabel="Mars"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="04" itemLabel="Avril"/><f:selectItem itemValue="05" itemLabel="May"/><f:selectItem itemValue="06" itemLabel="Juin"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="07" itemLabel="Juillet"/><f:selectItem itemValue="08" itemLabel="Aout"/><f:selectItem itemValue="09" itemLabel="Septembre"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="Octobre"/><f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="Novembre"/><f:selectItem itemValue="12" itemLabel="Decembre"/>
                                 </h:selectOneMenu>

                                 <h:selectOneMenu  id="annee" value="#{AddPerson.annee}" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1940" itemLabel="1940"/> <f:selectItem itemValue="1941" itemLabel="1941"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1942" itemLabel="1942"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1943" itemLabel="1943"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1944" itemLabel="1944"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1945" itemLabel="1945"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1946" itemLabel="1946"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1947" itemLabel="1947"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1948" itemLabel="1948"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1949" itemLabel="1949"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1950" itemLabel="1950"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1951" itemLabel="1951"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1952" itemLabel="1952"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1953" itemLabel="1953"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1954" itemLabel="1954"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1955" itemLabel="1955"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1956" itemLabel="1956"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1957" itemLabel="1957"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1958" itemLabel="1958"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1959" itemLabel="1959"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1960" itemLabel="1960"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1961" itemLabel="1961"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1962" itemLabel="1962"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1963" itemLabel="1963"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1964" itemLabel="1964"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1965" itemLabel="1965"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1966" itemLabel="1966"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1967" itemLabel="1967"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1968" itemLabel="1968"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1969" itemLabel="1969"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1970" itemLabel="1970"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1971" itemLabel="1971"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1972" itemLabel="1972"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1973" itemLabel="1973"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1974" itemLabel="1974"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1975" itemLabel="1975"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1976" itemLabel="1976"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1977" itemLabel="1977"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1978" itemLabel="1978"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1979" itemLabel="1979"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1980" itemLabel="1980"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1981" itemLabel="1981"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1982" itemLabel="1982"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1983" itemLabel="1983"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1984" itemLabel="1984"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1985" itemLabel="1985"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1986" itemLabel="1986"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1987" itemLabel="1987"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1988" itemLabel="1988"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1989" itemLabel="1989"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1990" itemLabel="1990"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1991" itemLabel="1991"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1992" itemLabel="1992"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1993" itemLabel="1993"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1994" itemLabel="1994"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1995" itemLabel="1995"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1996" itemLabel="1996"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1997" itemLabel="1997"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1998" itemLabel="1998"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1999" itemLabel="1999"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2000" itemLabel="2000"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2001" itemLabel="2001"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2002" itemLabel="2002"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2003" itemLabel="2003"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2004" itemLabel="2004"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2005" itemLabel="2005"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2006" itemLabel="2006"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2007" itemLabel="2007"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2008" itemLabel="2008"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2009" itemLabel="2009"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2010" itemLabel="2010"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2011" itemLabel="2011"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2012" itemLabel="2012"/> 
                                 </h:selectOneMenu>

                </td></tr>


            <tr><td>   <br /> <h:outputLabel value="fax"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.fax}" /></td></tr>
               <tr><td>            <br /> <h:outputLabel value="profession"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.profession}" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td>             <br /> <h:outputLabel value="adresse"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.adresse}" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td>             <br />  <h:outputLabel value="code Postal"/><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.codePostal}" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td>             <br />  <h:outputLabel value="Domaine de Competence"/>
                         <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{AddPerson.domain}" id="domaine" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Domaine de Competence-- " itemValue="0"/> 
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{AddPerson.listDomaine}" />
                                       </h:selectOneMenu></td></tr>



                          <tr style="width:800px"><td style="width:500px">     <br />  <h:outputLabel value="Files"/>
                                       <h:panelGroup style="display:inline;color:yellow;"> 
                                           <p:fileUpload style="display:inline" fileUploadListener="#{AddPerson.fileUpload}"    
                                                sizeLimit="500000"   
                                                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  

                                       </h:panelGroup></td></tr>



                          <tr><td>   <br />  <h:outputLabel value="butt"/> <h:commandButton style="color:red;"   value="Add User" action="#{AddPerson.addUserDB}"  /></td></tr>


                </h:form></table>
```

Comment: Not sure if it will help but, You better wrap the table with form instead of form with table, Also , I don't remember how it was in primefaces 2 , but in 3.x you need to add enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Also, using <br/> in a table...? There are better ways to achieve styling INMO, try to remove them and see if it helps

Comment: I have tried that too ,I have tried primefaces3.2 ,I have put the table in the form and add the enctype="multipart/form-data but no solution! I find this error as strange!

Comment: Have you tried replacing table with h:panelGrid ? Or with ul and li (different styling approaches than plain table ?

Comment: I have used h:panel as you advised me :)

Comment: and ? did it worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried replacing table with `<h:panelGrid` ? Or with `ul` and `li` (different styling approaches than plain table ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case check the Chrome element inspector and saw the default css Primefaces and I appeared so:

```
.ui-fileupload {
display: none;
}
```

What I did is overwrite the style in my css file like this:

```
.ui-fileupload { 
display: inline; 
}
```

Info:
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/